# Regular Expression as Php input filter For Pdo DSN host or host+port

Tags: php, regex, pdo

Right up front, I dislike Regular Expressions. It is desired to allow input of domain or domain + port options of the DSN to be set in a single input. Also that localhost is an option as well as subdomains.

The best I could come was acquired from an article called [*Domain name regular expression example*](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/domain-name-regular-expression-example/)

Which provides this expression for Java
`^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$`

It was realized that it almost works but the part for a period is `\\.` and should be `\.` in Php

From the [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php#refsect1-ref.pdo-mysql.connection-examples) some PDO_MYSQL DSN examples are:

```
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb
mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=testdb
```

The only part I want to perform the regular expression on is

```
localhost
localhost;port=3307
```

This is to be used for a filter of a HTML form as part of a Php based installation of a Php app (hope this make sense).

So this is what I came up with:

```
'/^((?!-)[a-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)(\.){0,1})+([a-z]{0,9})(?<!\.)((;port=){1}[0-9]{2,6}){0,1}$/i'
```

It is important that the string does not start or end with hyphens or contain whitespace.

Here is something more in depth https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/bc0cbcbb1df5c4b4361a 
and a link to the overall project https://github.com/CrandellWS/ams

Can this expression be shorter or optimized in order to help prevent end-user errors?

More importantly as Regular Expression is not my strongest point any possible gotchas that can be prevented from please explain how and why.

For My reference these 2 sites have been immensely helpful in figuring out Regular Expressions http://www.regexr.com/ and http://txt2re.com/

Comment: If you want to keep the same accuracy of the matches, it will be difficult to change it. btw. shorter regex is usually more complex not simpler. :)

Comment: Understood, so forget simpler I updated the question to ask about shorter or optimized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to check if it is valid,(without caring on about match groups):

```
^[^-][a-z0-9-]{0,63}[^-](\.[a-z]{0,9})*(;port=[0-9]{2,6})?$
```

If you are not so exact you could test:

```
^[^-][a-z0-9-]*[^-](\.[a-z]+)*(;port=[0-9]+)?$
```

or

```
^[^-][\w-]*[^-](\.\w+)*(;port=\d+)?$
```

But essentially the every time you shrink it you are losing accuracy

**Update 1:**

> `[\w\d-]*`  vs `[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}`  here the length of the string will not be checked
>
> `?` vs `{0,1}`  is equivalent (just shorter)
>
> `\d` vs `[0-9]` is equivalent (just shorter)
>
> `\w` vs `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is equivalent (just shorter)
>
> And no negative lookbehinds `(?<! ...)` they make everything a bit complicated

**missing accuracy:** It now there are some entries possible, that shouldn't be valid, since length checks are missing and now underscore is also allowed(before not)

**Update 2:**

To prevent spaces at the beginning characters just add this

```
^[^\s-][\w-]*[^\s-](\.\w+)*(;port=\d+)?$
```

> `[^\s-]` ... excludes **only** spaces or hyphens, any other character is allowed (even a dot)

But to get closer to your expression (without lookbehind)

```
^\w[\w-]*\w(\.\w+)*(;port=\d+)?$
```

and to remove the underscores, but it is a bit longer

```
^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9](\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(;port=\d+)?$
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if you explain what accuracy is being lost. Thanks for the way you are minimizing it helps me understand.

Comment: problem I am having with your expression's is hyphens and whitespace. It is desired that it does not start with or end with a hyphen or contain whitespace.  It seems I should use the one I came up with for best results. Thanks for your help in understanding.

Comment: @CrandellWS I update the answer, may be this can help(shine some light, to the greatness of regex ;-) ). Nevertheless this is all only an approximation, and leaves some room for user error.

Comment: Thank you for that update as it was not clear to me why `^[^-][\w-]*[^-](\.\w+)*(;port=\d+)?$` even allow spaces but it makes sense to me now thanks to your input. your help has been Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest try to make it more strict like this:

[example](https://regex101.com/r/dZ0uV7/1)

It dosen't consider unix_socket and it's not short but simple to understand. You can try to make it more precise.

UPDATED

Try also this [example](https://regex101.com/r/dZ0uV7/2)

Comment: thank you for the website resource I did not know about, though it seems my desired result is missed here I am updating the question

Comment: I forgot to mention that the resource doesn't support java regex. My example was for pcre(php). But I think you can edit your regex to work in java. Yes, please post a few examples of dsn you're working with and the example where your regex doesn't work

Comment: It works completely as far as I can tell. It was hoped to improve it or be told about any gotchas not in my foresight. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -2):

Let me surprise you that parameters in DSN can go in random order.

> This is to be used for a filter of a HTML form as part of a Php based installation of a Php app

For my life I won't understand why would you torture a user asking them to create a DSN-like string (which they likely have no idea of) and then torture yourself verifying it. Instead of just asking for separate host and (optional) port fields, just like any installation script in the world does.

Let me suggest you to make yourself familiar with some existing installation scripts, before starting for your own. One from Wordpress will do.

It just occured to me that may be you need help with PHP conditionals. Here you go:

```
if (isset($_POST['dbhost'])) {

    if ($_POST['dbport'])
    {
        $DB_PORT = $_POST['dbport']
    } else {
        $DB_PORT = 3306;
    }
    $DB_HOST = $_POST['dbhost'];
    $DB_DATABASE = $_POST['dbname'];
    $DB_USERNAME = $_POST['dbuser'];
    $DB_PASSWORD = $_POST['dbpass'];
    $DB_DSN = 'mysql:host=$DB_HOST;port=$DB_PORT;dbname=$DB_DATABASE";
```

This simple code will solve all your problems without Regular Expressions you don't like. I hope that your dislikes do not extend to simple conditionals though.

Comment: Because not everyone needs to input a port and those that will probably will understand `$DB_DSN = 'mysql:host='.$DB_HOST.';dbname='.$DB_DATABASE;`

Comment: perhaps you should review this script https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/bc0cbcbb1df5c4b4361a as you will see the database name, user, and  password are all separate fields while leaving the host able to accept the port. You are completely off topic. It should not matter WHY anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the php code suggestion, it has been in my thoughts of doing just that, but MY decision was to build and use a Regular Expression. This is for MY UNDERSTANDING of Regular Expressions and to gain experience there in. That is why http://stackoverflow.com/a/32753443/1815624 is the correct answer.

Comment: If you're knowledgeable of Php and have a desire to help, it would be nice to learn from the wisdom of another who has more experience. Though this would be outside of the scope of this particular question. I have a project on github and could use help with the framework. see: https://github.com/CrandellWS/ams/tree/master/htdocs/framework which has code I believe could be improved.